# Random mutagenesis with bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a string e.g.

```
1234567890
```

and I want to replace random positions of that string with corresponding position from a random sequence in another set of other strings e.g.

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZABCD
...
```

If I chose to make 3 replacements, the script should chose 3 random numbers e.g. 3,7,8; and 3 random sequences e.g. 1, 1, 3; make the replacements to generate the expected output:

```
12C456GB90
```

Is there a way to do this without significant looping? I wrote a simple bash script to generate a random position and a random sequence line then do 1 replacement, then repeat the process on the output, repeat, repeat. This works perfectly, however in my real-life files (much larger than the examples), I want to generate 10,000 or more replacements. Oh, and I will need to do this multiple times to generate multiple 'mutated' variant sequences.

EDIT: At the moment I am using something like this:

```
#chose random number between 1 and the number of characters in the string
randomposition=$(jot -r 1 1 $seqpositions)
#chose a random number between 1 and the number of lines in the set of potential replacement strings
randomline=$(jot -r 1 1 $alignlines)
#find the character at randomline:randomposition
newAA=$(sed -n "$randomline,$randomline p" $alignmentfile | cut -c$randomposition)
#replace the character at 'string:randomposition' with the character at 'randomline:randomposition'
sed "s/./$newAA/$randomposition" $sequencefile
```

(with some additional bits, obviously) and just looping through this thousands of times

Comment: What is the application of this? Do you work in a field where this sort of thing may already be implemented by a field specific standard tool?

Comment: Looks like a computational biology question: I agree with @Kusalananda: give us a real-world example.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed biology based. The idea is that I have a protein sequence, and I want to mutate that sequence randomly-ish; that is, I want to mutate it randomly, but only allow specific characters (amino acid residues) that have been observed previously at that specific position i.e. by swapping with characters in my alignment file at the same position. By doing it this way, I keep the protein sequence resembling something true, while also maintaining some information about the frequency of characters at each position (mutation to a rare character only occurs rarely etc). Does that help?

Comment: I edited the original question to include the relevant parts of the script I am currently using. Perhaps someone can see how I could make it change more than one position at a time?

Comment: what "random mutagenesis" means and what is the expected result?!

Comment: Could you please include the expected output so we can work on it. currently, not clear what is the fruit is ?!

Comment: Sorry, obviously I'm not being clear! In the example of the original post, the expected output is '12C456GB90'; so it's a new string based on the original, but has a specified number of changes. The changes occur at random positions within the string, and the the resulting character comes from the SAME position of a randomly chosen sequence from a set of strings. You can see that position 3 has been swapped in the original string (3) to that of position 3 of string1 from the set of strings provided (C). My actual strings and sequence sets are much much larger than this, so it's hard to show

Comment: Still not clear to me. You said, you want to generate 10000 replacements can you post additional examples for more clarification! Do you expect a list of 10000 "random mutagenesis" similar to 12C456GB90 where there are two numbers at the beginning and two at the end?

Comment: If I were to make 1 replacement, I would end up with 12**C**4567890; 2 replacements would give 12**C**456**G**890; 3 would give 12**C**456**GB**90... clearly 10,000 would be excessive with a 10 character string, but if my string is 30,000 characters, it would be ok. In my above example, I would like to know if I can do the 3 replacements in 1 step, rather than doing 1 replacement, then putting that new string in as the original for a second iteration, then a third.

Comment: Why second replacement is 12C456G890 where G came from and "GB" where it came from in the third replacement 12C456GB90?

Comment: These replacements come from the set of sequences given in the original post. The characters in the original string are replaced by a character at the same position of a randomly selected string from the second file. The "C" came from position 3 of sequence1; the G came from position 7 of sequence 1; the B came from position 8 of sequence 3. Both position, and source sequence should be chosen randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

This is strictly for amusement purposes; an equivalent program in `C` would be much simpler and orders of magnitude faster; as to `bash`, let's not even talk about ;-)

The following `perl` script will mutate a list of ~1M sequences, and ~10k alignments in about 10 seconds on my laptop.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# usage mutagen number_of_replacements alignment_file [ sequence_file ..]
use strict;
my $max = shift() - 1;
my $algf = shift;
open my $alg, $algf or die "open $algf: $!";
my @alg = <$alg>;

sub prand { map int(rand() * $_[0]), 0..$max }
while(<>){
    my @ip = prand length() - 1;
    my @op = prand scalar @alg;
    for my $i (0..$max){
        my $p = $ip[$i];
        substr $_, $p, 1, substr $alg[$op[$i]], $p, 1;
    }
    print;
}
```

Usage example:

```
$ cat seq
1634870295
5684937021
2049163587
6598471230
$ cat alg
DPMBHZJEIO
INTMJZOYKQ
KNTXGLCJSR
GLJZRFVSEX
SYJVHEPNAZ
$ perl mutagen 3 alg seq
1L3V8702I5
5684HE7Y21
2049JZC587
6598H7C2E0
```

If the generated `n` random numbers have to be different between them, then `prand` should be changed to:

```
sub prand {
    my (@r, $m, %h);
    die "more replacements than positions/alignments" if $max >= $_[0];
    for(0..$max){
        my $r = int(rand() * $_[0]);
        $r = ($r + 1) % $_[0] while $h{$r};
        $h{$r} = 1;
        push @r, $r;
    }
    @r;
}
```

A debug-enabled version, that will pretty-print the mutation with colors when given the `-d` switch:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# usage mutagen [-d] number_of_replacements alignment_file [ sequence_file ..]
use strict;

my $debug = $ARGV[0] eq '-d' ? shift : 0;
my $max = shift() - 1;
my $algf = shift;
open my $alg, $algf or die "open $algf: $!";
my @alg = <$alg>;

sub prand { map int(rand() * $_[0]), 0..$max } 
while(<>){
    my @ip = prand length() - 1;
    my @op = prand scalar @alg;

    if($debug){
        my $t = ' ' x (length() - 1);
        substr $t, $ip[$_], 1, $ip[$_] for 0..$max;
        warn "@ip | @op\n    $_    $t\n";
        for my $i (0..$max){
            my $t = $alg[$op[$i]];
            $t =~ s/(.{$ip[$i]})(.)/$1\e[1;31m$2\e[m/;
            printf STDERR " %2d %s", $op[$i], $t;
        }
    }
    for my $i (0..$max){
        my $p = $ip[$i];
        substr $_, $p, 1, substr $alg[$op[$i]], $p, 1;
    }
    print;
    if($debug){
        my @t = split "", $_;
        for my $i (0..$max){
            $_ = "\e[1;31m$_\e[m" for $t[$ip[$i]];
        }
        warn "  = ", @t, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I can't even begin to understand that, but it works perfectly. I bow down to you. Thanks so much

Comment: I notice the script breaks if you request more replacements than there are sequences in the alignment, which suggests that it will only access each alignment sequence once, right? Is it possible to chose a random alignment sequence each time, even if it has been chosen before? That way, in your usage example above, it would be possible to do >5 replacements (it's even possible, though unlikely, they all come from the same alignment sequence)

Comment: Yes that's very easy to do, it will even simplify the script a lot -- replace the `sub prand {...}` with sub `sub prand { map int(rand() * $_[0]), 0..$max }`.

Comment: @catchprj I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This linear would generate an infinite number of random keys:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
```

Sample output:

```
MB0JZZ85VI
2OKOY4JL61
2YN7B71Z6K
KH29TYCQ4K
B4N1XOFY5O
```

Explanation:

`/dev/random`, `/dev/urandom` or even `/dev/arandom` are special files that serve as pseudorandom number generators in the system. They allow access to environmental noise collected from device drivers and other sources, more information can be reached [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)

The [fold command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fold) in UNIX is a command line utility for folding contents of specified files, or standard input. By default it wraps lines at a maximum width of 80 columns. It also supports specifying the column width and wrapping by numbers of bytes. The flag `w` in the command `fold` represent the columns width and it can help, indirectly, to adjust for how many bytes would be included in the randomly generated keys.

The regex expression in the command `tr` controls for which characters would be included in the random keys.

`head -n` would adjust for how many random keys would be generated. For example, replacing `-n 1` by `10000` would generate 10.000 keys.

Comment: This would give a sequence of 10 random uppercase characters and/or digits, but it would not mutate a given string the way that the question asked about. Note that the strings in the question (the original one and the set of other strings) are not random. These (I assume) represent, for example, DNA that is mutated in different ways.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I appreciate your comment! Honestly, I could not find simpler method to generate 10.000 replacements without looping, let's wait for the OP feedback and then we can go from there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your original `bash` attempt was slow because of the number of external processes being started.  Each random number called `jot`, and each string manipulation used two `sed` and a `cut`.

As you're using `bash`, and not pure `sh`, you can benefit from the [$RANDOM](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-RANDOM) variable, [Substring Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).  These make it possible to perform the replacements with no external commands -- not even any `bash` subshells.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$1
read sequence < $2
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a replacements < $3
len=${#sequence}
choices=${#replacements[*]}

while ((count--)) ; do
        pos=$(($RANDOM % $len))
        choice=$(($RANDOM % $choices))
        replacement=${replacements[$choice]}
        sequence=${sequence:0:$pos}${replacement:$pos:1}${sequence:$((pos+1))}
done

echo "$sequence"
```

Note that $RANDOM won't exceed 32767, so if your sequences are bigger than that (or even approaching that size), you will need something more complex than `$RANDOM % maximum`.

This is still unlikely to beat a dedicated scripting language for speed, let alone a compiled language.